# How to make the Top N filter in SSRS sort in ascending order

Tags: reporting-services

I'm building a report which allows the user to choose the top number of product sales by highest quantity sold for a site, for a selected date range. I have filtered the tablix using the 'top N' function on quantity sold and the value is linked to a 'top selling' parameter, which is a drop down of default values (eg. 10,20,30 ect). So the user can select the '10' value to see the top 10 sales by quantity, for their chosen date range and site.

The issue I appear to be having is the filter brings back the chosen top sample but the results are in descending order (lowest to highest). Ideally, the top x sales should be in ascending order and despite trying to sort the tablix into the correct order, it hasn't worked.

Is there a way to have the top x sales (by qty) in highest to lower order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused Ascending and Descending... Lowest to Highest is Ascending.

Regardless - You can simply pick descending instead of ascending  (Z-A instead of A-Z) in the **Order** tab...

Or if you are sorting in your SQL query - You can add **DESC** to the end of the order by clause